# String Parsing in Java and android

Tags: java, string, parsing

I want to parse the data below  in java. What approach shall I follow? 
I want to neglect `;` inside `{ }`.

Thus `Version`, `Content`, `Provide`, `UserConfig` and `Icon` as name and corresponding values.

```
Version:"1";
Content:2013091801;
Provide:"Airtel";
UserConfig : 
{
  Checksum = "sha1-234448e7e573b6dedd65f50a2da72245fd3b";
  Source = "content\\user.ini";
};
Icon: 
{
  Checksum = "sha1-a99f835tytytyt3177674489770e613c89390a8c4";
  Source = "content\\resept_ico.bmp";
};
```

Here we can't use `String.split(";")` function.

Comment: this is not xml so I removed the tag

Comment: I think you can use regular expressions to do that.
Just find the values you need with those keywords.

Comment: ';' inside '{}' is problem if i use regular expression.

Comment: remove the last';' and add '{' '}' into begin and end. then it becomes a json string, use JsonObject to prase it

Comment: thanks very much Ivan for reply,i will check your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been lot more complex to convert using the `Regex` and then creating a method to extract the required fields,
What I did was **converted the above mentioned input to Json compatible string** and then used [GSON library by google](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse the `String` to my customized class,

```
class MyVer
{
    String Version;
    long Content;
    String Provide;
    Config UserConfig;
    Config Icon;
    String Source;              
}

class Config
{
    String Checksum;
    String Source;          
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String s = "Version:\"1\";Content:2013091801;Provide:\"Airtel\";UserConfig :{  Checksum = \"sha1-234448e7e573b6dedd65f50a2da72245fd3b\";  Source = \"content\\user.ini\";};Icon:{  Checksum = \"sha1-a99f835tytytyt3177674489770e613c89390a8c4\";  Source = \"content\\resept_ico.bmp\";};";                

    String startingBracePattern = Pattern.quote("{");
    String endBracePattern = Pattern.quote("}");
    s=s.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\"), "\\\\\\\\"); //Replacing all the single \ with double \\
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s*"+startingBracePattern +"\\s*", "\\{\""); //Replacing all the `spaces { spaces` with  `{"`  MEANS all the { to replace with {"
    s = s.replaceAll(";\\s*"+endBracePattern +"\\s*;", "\\};"); //Replacing all the `; spaces } spaces ;` with  `},"` MEANS all the ;}; to replace with };

    s = "{\"" + s.substring(0, s.length() - 1) +"}";    //Removing last ; and appending {" and }        
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s*:", "\":");                   // Replacing all the `space with :` with `":`       
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s*;\\s*", ",\"");               //Replacing all the `spaces ; spaces` with `,"`
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s*=\\s*", "\":");               //Replacing all the `spaces = spaces` with  `":`

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MyVer newObj = gson.fromJson(s, MyVer.class);
}
```

This converts and give you the object of `MyVer` and then you can access all the variables.

**NOTE:** You can alter the code little to replace all `\r\n` if they are present in your input variables. I have not used them and your actual data supplied in question in a single line for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

JSON sounds **a lot** easier in this case..

.. however, *if you were* to do this using regular expressions, one way would be:

for the simple cases (eg. version):

```
// look for Version: some stuff ;
Pattern versionPattern = Pattern.compile("Version\\s*:\\s*\"\\w+\"\\s*;");

// the whole big string you're looking in
String bigString = ...; // the entire string from before can go here

// create a matcher for the "version pattern"
Matcher versionMatcher = versionPattern.matcher(bigString);

// check if there's a match in the string
if(versionMatcher.find()) {
    // get the matching substring
    String matchingSubstring = bigString.substring(
            versionMatcher.start(),
            versionMatcher.end()
        );
    // we need the area between the quotes
    String version = matchingSubstring.split("\"")[1];

    // do something with it
    ...
}
```

for the harder (multi-line) cases (eg. UserConfig):

```
// look for UserConfig : { some stuff };
Pattern userconfigPattern = Pattern.compile("UserConfig\\s*:\\s*{[^}]*};", Pattern.DOTALL);

// create a matcher for the "user config pattern"
Matcher userconfigMatcher = userconfigPattern.matcher(bigString);

// check if there's a match in the string
if(userconfigMatcher.find()) {
    // get the matching substring
    String matchingSubstring = bigString.substring(
            userconfigMatcher.start(),
            userconfigMatcher.end()
        );
    // we need the area between the curly braces
    String version = matchingSubstring.split("[{}]")[1];

    // do something with it
    ...
}
```

---

**EDIT:** this is probably an easier way

```
// split the input string into fields
String[] fields = bigString.split("[^:]+:([^{;]+;)|({[^}]+};)");

// for each key-value pair
for(String field : fields) {
    // the key and value are separated by colons
    String parts = field.split(":");

    String key = parts[0];
    String value = parts[1];

    // do something with them, or add them to a map
    ...
}
```

This last way splits the input string based on the assumption that each key-value pair consists of:

1. some (non-colon) characters at the start, followed by
2. a colon,
3. either

   -> some characters that are not curly braces or semi-colons (for simple attributes), or

   -> curly braces containing some characters that are not curly braces
4. a semi-colon

Answer (score 0):

Here is json solution

```
    str = "{" + str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(";")).replace(";\n}", "}") + "}";
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        String version = json.getString("Version");
        JSONObject config = json.getJSONObject("UserConfig");
        String source = config.getString("Source");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

since ";" should not be in front of "}"

```
   Source = "content\\resept_ico.bmp";
}
```

we need remove them